# js reading string values as html

Tags: javascript, html

I have several strings containing HTML elements, for example:

```
$("textarea").change(function(){
        var $html = $("#html").val();
        var $css = $("#css").val();
        var $js = $("#js").val();
        var so = "<style>";
        var sc = "</style>";
        var jso = "<script>window.onload=function(){";
        var jsc = "}</script>";
        var ho = "<body>";
        var hc = "</body>";
        $("iframe#display").html(so + $css + sc + jso + js + jsc + ho + $html + hc);
});
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I am using the jQuery `.html` function to insert content, but the error is cropping up where this has always worked before. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: WHERE are you getting this error? What specific line?

Comment: You might get more  responses if you create a fiddle (jsfiddle, jsbin, etc) with you HTML and JS.

Comment: @user1032531 — Stackoverflow has supported [inline live demos](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for yonks. There's no need to resort to a third party hosting service.

Comment: @user1032531 That might lead into a recursive implosion, since it looks like the OP is trying to _implement_ some fiddle-like capability :-)

Comment: @Quentin  Agree. Sorry.

Comment: You are using variable name `js` but it is defined as `$js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`</script>` will terminate a script element. If you have it in the middle of a string, it will terminate it there.

Move your script to an external `.js` file or express the sequence of characters as `<\/script>`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd have thought it would just be read as a string, and anything inside would be regarded not as HTML, just the contents of a string.

Comment: No. The HTML parser isn't aware of JS syntax and just looks for the first `</script>`.